# pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Windows\System32"

Tags: flutter

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Windows\System32". pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Windows\System32".)
```

hi everyone 
I got this error message every time when I tried to create a flutter project by an android studio or by cmd 
I checked flutter doctor command and appear no problems about flutter installation
so any advice about this problem?

[error message when I used android studio [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFvxP.png)

[flutter doctor message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPldJ.png)

Answer (score 4):

You can try below steps:

- First, you reboot(restart) your PC.
- Before opening anything, you delete your `flutter` folder.
- Unzipped a new flutter installation into the same directory.
- Inside your project directory You run `flutter packages get`
- Then open the IDE and everything will be working.

Refer [flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32033) for more information.

Comment: i did the same steps but still i got the same error

Comment: Delete `.pub-cache` file (from inside **flutter** folder) and then run `flutter package get`.